# Put "Dev Qs not allowed" on Ask Question page for new users?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add a note to the “Ask a Question Page” to reinforce that dev questions are off-topic](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/484/add-a-note-to-the-ask-a-question-page-to-reinforce-that-dev-questions-are-off)

The site FAQ clearly mentions that development questions are off-topic here, but still I encounter development questions here, almost every day. The problem is nobody reads FAQ. Seriously!

I suggest to put "Development Questions are Off-topic here" text on Ask Question page for new users. While every point of FAQ deserves this, I am demanding only this one because of practical problem we are facing.